# Any prescribed zone or similar concept for extra-low voltage/DC and data concealed wiring?

Tags: wiring, uk, ethernet, data-wiring, low-voltage

Is there any concept of 'prescribed zones' (née 'safe zones') - or interaction with those for concealed mains wiring - for other concealed cables?

Answer (score 1):

Simple rules of thumb for data &/or audio lines…

1. Cross mains at 90°
2. If forced to travel in parallel, maintain at least 2ft, preferably 3 or more from any mains. Keep parallel runs as short at you possibly can.

These are 'overkill' rules. Balanced line audio can pretty much ignore all of the above. Good shielded or twisted pair data can flirt with it, but try to stick to it as much as possible. If you can, it's better to route in completely opposite directions around a room, so the twain never meet.

Comment: Thanks, so that's 'just' best practice to avoid interference/crosstalk, rather than building regulation? And effectively means runs 2/3ft from fittings, corners, and ceiling prescribed zones - and not worrying about the possibility of future additions? (I'm not sure what the alternative would be.)

Comment: I don't know of any regulations on this - though I've never looked them up. As a retired audio engineer who started 'playing' at IT support 30 years ago, this was always just the 'word of mouth' common sense ruleset we applied in any installation. We would also keep data & audio separated, even if we were running balanced line - better wire it once than twice. If you get crosstalk from data into audio, bang goes your expensive recording studio… re-wire time.